# Изменение dll и хуки

Tags: c#, dll, hook

Есть dll с кодом на C#, которая имеет очень много зависимостей, так что у меня не получится декопильнуть, переписать и закомпилить опять в dll. Как мне можно изменить код в dll без перекомпиливания/подключения зависимостей. Так же думал о хуках. Можно ли в C# хукануть какую-либо функцию в dll? Что бы можно было её переписать?

Comment: Буду на ТЫ, так как уже все сыты по горло майнерами, не думаю что здесь кто-то будет помогать.
Если dll твоя, то и декомпиляция не нужна,  так вывод ясный ...

Comment: @DigitalCore Какими майнерами? Я хочу переписать функции unity. Я это делаю в благих целях

Comment: И где эта `dll` которую вы хотите переписать.

Comment: @DigitalCore Ну, у меня на диске лежит. UnityEngine.Networking

Comment: В C# есть такая вещь, как override и то, что позволяет разработчик (к примеру [NetworkManager.OnServerAddPlayer](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager.OnServerAddPlayer.html)) - вы без труда сможете изменить на свой лад. Не все методы можно переписать, ибо сами понимаете, это безопасность как от "дурака", так и от других не предвиденных последствий. Посмотрите, может вашу задачу можно вовсе по другому решить, а не переписывать то, чего не дозволено.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Только если можно написать свой NetworkManager с нуля. Ибо unity в недоступном коде спавнит объекты при запуске сцены, а мне это не надо, и погуглив, я не нашел как это выключить. Ну а так же у них почему-то не так работает эвент, который мне нужен